# Outlook Add-in - Connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, outlook-addin

May I know is there any tutorial or guide for me to learn how to connect to the SQL Server for my Outlook Add-in project? Been searching high and low through the web but couldn't find any decent guide. Appreciate if you can provide a link to the guide.

Thanks!

Comment: What language is your add-in written in? If it's .Net, just use the standard ado or sqlclient methods for the language.

Comment: @DB101 HTML/CSS/JS. So i just need to use PHP to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a PHP driver for SQL Server. The following link will show you how to use PHP to connect to SQL.

[MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: why this didn't strike to me earlier.. I though html/js must be used in add-in only, never thought of other language is permitted too.. thanks for the heads up. I'll rewrite everything in .NET since I am more familiar with that.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily import contacts into Outlook with a .csv file.

```
Open SQL Server Management Studio
Connect to database
Goto Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Text
Under Output format choose Comma Delimited
Confirm the "Include column headers" box is checked
Click OK
Open a new query window
Run your query
```

Similarly, consider exporting your dats sets from SQL Server, as a CSV, and import the same into Outlook.